# Camel jsch component

Tags: apache-camel, scp, jsch

Can some one provide an example of a working camel route for jsch component? I need to use scp from camel. I tried:

```
from("file:tmp/")
.to("scp://server?username=user&password=pass");
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

Check your logs... maybe do you need a **knownHostsFile**.

I did something like this:

```
scp://server/output/?username=user&password=pass&knownHostsFile=C:\\llave.txt"
```

(Sorry for my english)